# PHP: Format a numeric string by inserting comma

Tags: php, regex, string, formatting

I need a way to convert a number into formatted way by inserting comma at suitable places. Can it be done using regex?

Example:

```
12345 => 12,345
1234567 =>1,234,567
```

Comment: I don't know if php has it or not, but I would expect php to have some kind of formatting function that does this for you (an hopefully is culture-sensitive).

Comment: I wonder if people use Google before coming here...

Comment: Google will now send you here. :(

Comment: Just for the fun of it: s/(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/$1,/g

Comment: Please remember that not everything in the world is best solved with a regex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no need go for regex , you can easily do it using the [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function.

```
echo number_format(12345); // prints 12,345
echo number_format(1234567); // prints 1,234,567
```

.

```
$arr = array(
        1234567890,
        123456789,
        12345678,
        1234567,
        123456,
        12345,
        1234,
        123,
    );

foreach($arr as $num) {
    echo number_format($num)."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1,234,567,890
123,456,789
12,345,678
1,234,567
123,456
12,345
1,234
123
```

Answer (score 0):

For Integer value

```
$intVal=2151;

echo number_format((string)$intVal); // output -> 2,151
```